# mysqli update - copy one value into another throwing error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Throwing 'Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object' on the $mysqli->prepare.  The original worked perfectly fine.  Is this not possible in mysqli?

Guess I should have made it clear that mysqli is set correctly as in include - $mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_database);

original :

```php
mysql_query("UPDATE test_users SET lastIP=currIP, dtLastLogin=dtCurrLogin WHERE user='".$user."'");
```

new mysqli version:

```php
function user_login($user)
{
// Update user's last ip and last login date in db  
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE test_users SET lastIP = currIP, dtLastLogin = dtCurrLogin WHERE user= ?");
// bind params
$stmt->bind_param('s', $user);
// execute prepared statement
$stmt->execute();
// close statement
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Your `user_login` function has no idea what `$mysqli` is.

Comment: `$mysqli` should contain your DB credentials inside your function, or do as [**Mike W suggested**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19932242/1415724)

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post.  $mysqli is correctly set on another page and included so that is not the issue.

Comment: The error `'Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object' on the $mysqli->prepare` say it well : `$mysqli` not exists in your function body. As @MikeW suggested you, `Either declare it as a global variable, or pass it in as an argument.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you want to do with `mysqli`, but you haven't initialised the variable `$mysqli` in your function.

Either declare it as a `global` variable, or pass it in as an argument.

Comment: I edited my post - it is set properly through its own page which is included.  Other pages are working fine I am just running into an issue with this particular bit of code.

Comment: The words _in your function_ are key. Just because `$mysqli` exists _somewhere_ doesn't mean it's in scope _inside_ your function.